# If a request times out on an intermediate device, how are packets able to travel to the next device?

Tags: linux, networking

I noticed in many traceroutes that when `*        *        *     Request timed out` appears somewhere in the middle hop, the packets are able to make it to the subsequent device.

```
  3    13 ms     8 ms     9 ms  pos-0-3-0-0-cr01.newyork.ny.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.90.57]
  4    95 ms   100 ms     9 ms  xe-10-1-0.edge1.NY.exampleISP1.net [10.78.169.45]
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6   809 ms   808 ms     * ms  nyc-core-01.inet.example2.com [192.168.33.10]
```

On the 5th hop, when the request times out, how is it possible that the packets are able to go to the 6th device?  I assume "* * * request timed out" means that the 5th device is unreachable for some reason (ex. it does not accept icmp packets.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` just means that the fifth device didn't return any ICMP "time exceeded" message (or that the response was filtered out somewhere else between you and that particular device). It's still successfully routing packets (as evidenced by the fact that you can reach a device "further away").

[This Wikkipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) has more details on how Traceroute operates.